# Kill login with google id session

Tags: session

My application enables a user with valid gmail id to login to the app. The app's logout is unable to end the session created by gmail user. It seems it is taking the auth token from the cookies created during the login with google session. Can anybody hint me as how to kill the session.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which server side language are you using ?

Comment: JSP/Java spring mvc 3.0